# Problems constraining a non-geo-nodes object to follow a geo-nodes-modified curve

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

Here's my issue:
I have a complex curve object. I used geometry nodes' "resample curve" node to evenly distribute its vertices so my car objects (with no geometry nodes) can follow it at a linear speed. However, this creates a new issue -- the "follow path constraint" i have on my cars appear to evaluate before the geometry nodes modifier, so they're still just following the original curve without the resampling.

I know I can add a geometry node network to the cars with a "sample curve" node to make them follow the new resampled curve, but unfortunately these cars have several materials and children that I would need to recreate in geo nodes.

Is there a simple way to solve this problem that I'm overlooking?

Comment: I hope someone has a better answer, because this is, at best, a workaround. You could try converting the curve to a mesh then back to a curve. Constructive modifiers cannot be applied on curves, and the conversion to a mesh automatically also applies the GeoNodes modifier. Since a curve is what you want, you'll then need to convert it back. The drawback if that you can no longer modify you GeoNodes setup, and to be able to go back, you'll need to keep a copy of the original curve with the modifier still active.